# Missing .bat file

Tags: android, sdk, batch-file

[2013-02-20 12:32:44 - SDK Manager] Missing %s file in Android SDK.
[2013-02-20 12:32:44 - SDK Manager] android.bat

above error pops up every time I try to open Android SDK manager

I can't find a file named "android.bat" file in

C:\Program Files\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64\sdk\tools

swt.jar exist in following directory

C:\Program Files\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64\sdk\tools\lib\x86_64

I just started android developing... so please kindly bear with me and help me to slove this problem :)

thanx alot in advance.

Comment: Extract the Bundle zip file again and can you move your sdk in C:\<Any folder name>\ instead of "Program Files"??

Comment: I tried it... after extracting to C:\ADT_Bundle\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64 when i clicked on SDK manager it opened up but when i closed it & tried to open SDK manager again same error pops up...

Comment: Anyone have a solution for this? please..

Answer (score 2):

OK!! after searching for days and days i found out

even after downloading & adding the "android.bat" file to 'C:\ADT_Bundle\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64\sdk\tools' when later you try to run sdk manager you'll still get the same error if you don't **"PAUSE/STOP" virus guard** before opening 'SDK Manager'.

It worked for me. I hope this helped.. tnx everyone for your effort appreciate it.. :)

Comment: Where to find "PAUSE/STOP" virus guard?

Answer (score 2):

The Best Solution i have is download the SDK Tools Only From: http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

->Other Download Options->SDK Tools Only->android-sdk_r24.*.*-windows.zip
.
and extract it into your sdk location where the tools folder is required...

Answer (score 0):

Best method to solve this issue is to go to the sdk/temp folder. There you will find a zip file with a name like "tools_r24.0.1-windows" (version number will be different)

Copy it to someplace and extract it. Inside the extracted folder you'll have a folder named 'tools'

Copy that folder to sdk/ and replace the current tools folder in sdk/